# Template function argument deduction with enable_if - reference to pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

Maybe there is good solution that work on g++ 4.6.{3,4} ? 
You can check in on https://godbolt.org/

```
#include <type_traits>
class A{};
class B{};
class C{
    public:
    A* a;
    B* b;
};

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type,A*>::value>::type* = nullptr >
void f(T&& t) { 
    return;
}

int main() { 
    C c;
    auto& cRef = c;
    f(cRef.a);
    f(c.a);
}
```

g++ /tmp/enable_if.cpp -std=c++0x

```
/tmp/enable_if.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/tmp/enable_if.cpp:20:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(A*&)’
/tmp/enable_if.cpp:20:13: note: candidate is:
/tmp/enable_if.cpp:13:6: note: template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<_MemPtr>::type, A*>::value, void>::type* <anonymous> > void f(T&&)
/tmp/enable_if.cpp:21:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(A*&)’
/tmp/enable_if.cpp:21:10: note: candidate is:
/tmp/enable_if.cpp:13:6: note: template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<_MemPtr>::type, A*>::value, void>::type* <anonymous> > void f(T&&)
```

Comment: Please keep the title as a short summary of the problem you have, not as a piece of crucial information (like showing error messages etc.). If you have a build error, then copy-paste (as text) the full and complete output into the question body.

Comment: thnx for your comments, fixed :)

Answer (score 6):

The feature that allows you to default a function template parameter was introduced in C++11. Your compiler actually does not have a full support for this feature. As a workaround, you can put `std::enable_if` as a function return type:

```
template<typename T >
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type,A*>::value>::type f(T&& t) { 
    return;
}
```

Comment: thnx, out actual function return type is bool, but putting enable_if in function arguments also work.

Comment: @Roma - You can specify a second argument to `enable_if`, that it should expose as `::type`. So you can put it in the return type even if you need to return `bool`.